# Properly Using EOF in C

Tags: c, eof, do-while, if-statement

I'm new to programming and I really want to learn writing a decent program. I am not exactly sure how to use EOF. My program was compiled and when I run it, it works fine except for the EOF part. The program is supposed to return a -1 value (after using CTRL+z) to the main function, and will print a statement then will close the program. The -1 is a different value from the -1 of EOF per se.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
//Function Declaration
int inputFunction (int num);

int main (void)
{
    //Local Declarations
    int num;
    do
    {    
    inputFunction (num);

    if (num < 0 || num > 100)
            inputFunction (num);
    else
        inputFunction (num);
    }while (num != -1);
    return 0;
}
int inputFunction (int num)
{
    int rc;

    do
    {
    printf("Enter an integer from 0 to 100: \n");
    rc = scanf("%d", &num);
       {
       if (rc != EOF)
              {
              if (num < 0 || num >100)
                 {
                 printf("ERROR\n");
                 return num;
                 }
              else
                  {
                 return num;
                 }
              }
       else
           {
           num = -1;
           return num;
       }
       }  
    }while (rc != EOF);
    }
```

Comment: @orangepage Try `int inputFunction (int& num); `

Comment: @Red: I suspect that pointers might be a bit too advanced for a person with a question like this.

Comment: @Red this is C not C++, there is no such thing.

Comment: @Wiz OP failed to tag it properly.

Comment: @Red I beg to differ, it uses `stdio.h` not `cstdio` and only c functions (printf/scanf/EOF vs cout/>>/npos). How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @Wiz Really? Wow.  Just in case you didn't know, C++ is superset of C, and the above code compiles fine with `g++`.

Comment: Just because it compiles fine doesn't change the fact that you will be compiling C code using a C++ compiler. FYI, it's not a strict superset of C.

Comment: @Arlen C++ is not a superset of C.  That has not been true for decades.  (Well, at least one decade, but it may as well be a millenia.)

Answer (score 4):

The variable `num` is never assigned in `main`. You call `inputFunction` and it returns a value, but you ignore the value it returns.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII value for CTRL-Z (^Z), which is often used as an end-of-file marker in DOS is 26 (decimal).And remember you are passing variable num in main as **call by value**  not as reference so it would contain garbage value when you compare it.

Answer (score 1):

As Gabe has stated you need to assign the return value of inputFunction() in order to use it - because variables in functions have *local* scope. So every time you are calling inputFunction() in main() you should be doing it like so:

```
num = inputFunction(num);
```

Otherwise the value of num in inputFunction() is lost when program execution returns to main(). This is the main reason your program is not performing as expected.

There are also some logic problems with your code. In the first if/else statement in main(), both statements produce exactly the same result. Other behaviour might not be exactly what you want to do either.

I think you might benefit from planning out with pen and paper what you want the program to do. One way is to "map out" what the program will do with arrows etc (a flowchart). Or you can start with a 1-2 sentence description of the goal, and then gradually expand that into more and more detail until you have a series of tasks that the program will do, which you can then convert to code.